# Approximation of Sin(2) within 10^-4

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, approximation

I am having some trouble with this problem. So far, I am thinking to use a similar approach to finding the approximation of sin(x) per guidance of my textbook.

This would get me something along the lines of: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty = \frac{x^{(2^k-1)}(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k-1)!}$

and then $$x- \frac {x^3}6 + .. $$

How would I proceed?

Respectfully

Comment: What is the difficulty you're facing? You clearly know the formula ... With a calculator, the sum is fairly easy to calculate. Just keep adding terms and see when the answer converges to the value, with error smaller than the mentioned value.

Comment: @MattiP.: "You clearly know the formula" but fixing the typo in the exponent would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The terms

$$2,-\frac86,\frac{32}{120},-\frac{128}{5040},\frac{512}{362880},-\frac{2048}{39916800}$$

will suffice, as the last one is below $10^{-4}$ (and the series alternates).

Hence

$$\frac{141782}{155925}\approx0.9093$$

---

Note that you will get a better convergence by evaluating

$$\cos\left(2-\frac\pi2\right)$$ with the Taylor series

$$1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\cdots$$

because the argument is smaller.

Comment: Ok this makes a lot of sense. Since it is alternating series, I plug in 2 to x values until I have a solution that is less than 10^-4 or less than .0001! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance!

Answer (score 4):

write the remainder term in the Taylor series set it less than $10^{-4}$ 
you will get a value of n.
now write $T_n$ and put the value  $x=2$

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!} (x - c)^k + \dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(z)}{(n + 1)!} (x - c)^{n+1},$$

remainder term $$R_n(x; c) = \dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(z)}{(n + 1)!} (x - c)^{n+1}.$$

$z$ is between $x$ and $c$.
hope it helps

Comment: Alternatively, compute until the terms stay smaller than $10^{-4}$ as this is an alternating series.